# Django Sphinx Foreign key search

Tags: django, django-sphinx

I'm trying to create full text search on model, everything goes fine
when
searching TextFields but I have a problem with ForeignKey field.

How can i do that? Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Model example:

class Model1(models.Model):

```
 text_field =models.TextField(max_length=250)
 fk_field = models.ForeignKey('Model2')
```

class Model2(models.Model):

```
 text_field = models.TextField(max_length=250)
```

Thanks

R.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see your `sphinx.conf`.

Well for this which creating your `indexer` in `sphinx.conf` you need to specify what fields you select. After that what fields from your sql you select to be put as attributes (i.e. non searchable fields).

I suppose search with foreign-key fields are just as normal search. What particular difficulty/error are you facing?